# Trying to Exclude Unit Tests from Code Coverage

Tags: sonarqube, nant

I am trying to exclude the unit test projects/folders from the code coverage analysis since it is inflating the code coverage percentage.

I have different layers/projects and unit test projects for each of those.  As shown below.

```
Solution
  DataAccess
  Business
  Service
  Model
  Test.DataAccess
  Test.Business
  Test.Service
  Test.Model
```

How do I exclude any folder/project that has "Test.*" in its name/path?  I want to exclude everything within those folders.

I've tried the patterns below (and many others):

```
**\*Test.*\*
*Test.*\*
Test.*\*
**/*Test.*/*
*Test.*/*
Test.*/*
```

I cannot get it to exclude the unit test files.  It doesn't seem to recognize wildcards within the directory name.

Comment: Try again using "/" instead of "\"

Comment: I've tried the slashes both ways.  I'll double check it though and let you know.

Comment: I've retried the exclusions with slashes going both forward and backward.  Neither works.  It doesn't seem to accept wildcards within the folder name.  In fact, every example I've seen only shows the wildcards within the file name/file extension.  If it cannot handle wildcards within the folder name, that's pretty lame.

Comment: You might well be right. The only option I see is to check the [source code](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube). Something like "public class ExclusionFilters"

Comment: Is this .NET code? And if so, how are you analyzing? Test projects should be [excluded automatically](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Miscellaneous+Advanced+Usages)

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam Yes, this is .NET code.  I'll look over the link you've included.  Maybe we are not doing something properly upstream.

Comment: From the link, this looks like a better solution to add the property within the csproj: 

To manually classify a project as a test project, mark it with <SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>:
.csproj
<PropertyGroup>
  <!-- Mark the project as being a test project -->
  <SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>
</PropertyGroup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam and @Isaiah4110 stated, a better solution was to have sonarQube exclude test projects all together.  I'm not sure why this wasn't happening by default in our case but our solution was to add the "SonarQubeTestProject" property to the *.csproj files.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <SonarQubeTestProject>true</SonarQubeTestProject>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar issue and I mentioned the file name pattern instead of the folder name to get by. So we had the unit test file names ending with either test.cs or tests.cs. So I added

```
**/*Tests.cs
**/*Test.cs
```

and it works like a charm!

Comment: I did end up doing this for now.  However, because it doesn't exclude the entire Test project, sonarQube still analyzes other classes within the project that do not have "test" within the file name.  We have things like wrappers and such that we use to test abstract base classes that we don't want to have code coverage statistics reported.  I'm going to look at the link G. Ann provided in the comments to the main question.